# Picture Shaped not working

Tags: vb.net, winforms, image

Th following code is not working when the `Picture shaped` form.

```
    Dim Img As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(My.Resources.imgpng)'ImgPng is a resource Image
    ' The color at Pixel(1,1) is rendered as transparent for the complete background.
    Img.MakeTransparent(Img.GetPixel(1, 1))
    Me.BackgroundImage = Img
    Me.TransparencyKey = Img.GetPixel(1, 1)
```

Can anybody Help me to get more closer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks man...

```
     Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Img As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(My.Resources.NewImage) 'NewImage is a resource Image
    ' The color at Pixel(1,1) is rendered as transparent for the complete background.
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    Dim Color = Img.GetPixel(0, 0)
    Me.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch ' To Adjust the Image
    Me.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Black
    Img.MakeTransparent(Drawing.Color.Black)
    Me.TransparencyKey = Drawing.Color.Black
    Me.BackgroundImage = Img
End Sub
```

For a change 'Img.MakeTransparent(Color)' is not required. Try to getva decent image with outlined border to eliminate bad edges...

Answer (score 1):

I set the form background to the same via this code and it worked:

```
Dim Img As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(My.Resources.imgpng)'ImgPng is a resource Image
' The color at Pixel(1,1) is rendered as transparent for the complete background.
Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
Dim Color = Img.GetPixel(0, 0)
Me.BackColor = Color
Img.MakeTransparent(Color)
Me.TransparencyKey = Color
Me.BackgroundImage = Img
```

And I used (0,0) for the transparency pixel though that should not matter unless your (1,1) was the wrong color.

Comment: (1,1) is the color of Image's First Pixel, (0,0) works but can you confirm quality of edges?

Comment: That was the reason I used (1,1) in hope to get some quality. I believe the other way to increase quality could be a shadow effect. Now when I've given you a code, can you please help me with that?... and Thanks for responding :) I'll try to use this once back @ home!

Comment: I would suggest formulating another question for the shadowing or other effects.